# GAE datastore cached entities under Python objects

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, dev-appserver

I have this code here: http://sprunge.us/TAjH?py

Why am I getting `10` instead of `1` (or what is in the DB)? Also, any new retrieved python object (as entity) has the very same ID (and maybe even memory address). Why that? How should I proceed in order to have different objects with the real value stored under the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Answered it here: [How do I refresh an NDB entity from the datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409955/how-do-i-refresh-an-ndb-entity-from-the-datastore)

So the `use_cache=False` is the solution, while retrieving from the datastore.